# Xml Validation Issue with unexpected list of elements

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, biztalk, xml-validation

I a standard Schema format as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://HR_XML_BizTalk_Project_Schemas.Schema1" targetNamespace="http://HR_XML_BizTalk_Project_Schemas.Schema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="UserDetails">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Any">
                <xs:complexType />
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But my partner sending the xml in below format.

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://HR_XML_BizTalk_Project_Schemas.Schema1">
  <UserDetails>
    <ID>ID_0</ID>
    <Name>Name_0</Name>
    <Account>Account_0</Account>
    <Amount>Amount_0</Amount>
  </UserDetails>
</ns0:Root>
```

I'm receiving the error as **"The element 'UserDetails' has invalid child element 'ID'. List of possible elements expected: 'Any'"**

As per my uderstanding, I have to tell my partner to don't send any data under UserDetails Record.
Otherwise, I have to delete the nodes, if there anything existing under UserDetails records before validation.

Is there any other options to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="Any">
```

This look for an element named `Any`
What you mean if probably any element :

```
<xs:any>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really intend to require an element named `Any` for the content of `UserDetails`?

If instead you wish to allow a sequence of any elements under `UserDetails`, change your XSD to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003"
           xmlns="http://HR_XML_BizTalk_Project_Schemas.Schema1"
           targetNamespace="http://HR_XML_BizTalk_Project_Schemas.Schema1"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="UserDetails">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then your partner's XML will be valid.

Note, however, that you're not communicating the requirements of your interface very well when you use `xsd:any`.  Better would be to state the actual requirements of your service unless you truly don't care what's under `UserDetails`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your XSD correctly it expects XML like that:

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://HR_XML_BizTalk_Project_Schemas.Schema1">
  <UserDetails>
    <Any></Any>
  </UserDetails>
</ns0:Root>
```

I am not sure what you would like to check, but your validator seems to behave correctly. Please explain what exactly you would like to do and for sure sombody will be able to help you.